# Using same variable name in component state and props with redux and I get error of undefined props

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-redux, react-props

I have components that needs to know if the user is logged with **Facebook** or not, so I use the function `mapStateToProps` to *map redux state to component props*.
At the same time, some components can login themselves the users, so they need local `state` to know if the *user is logged or not* (I can not update component props inside component itself).

When user logs in, they dispatch a `loggedIn` event.

Is it a best practice or am I doing something wrong?
I have components like this:

```
import ...

const FBSDK = require('react-native-fbsdk');
const {
    LoginButton,
    AccessToken,
    LoginManager
} = FBSDK;

class Settings extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            isLoggedIn: false,
        };
    }

    componentDidMount () {
        this._loadInitialState();
    }

    async _loadInitialState() {
        AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().then(
            (data) => {
                if (data) {
                    this.setState({
                        isLoggedIn: true,
                    });

                    // Dispatch loggedIn action
                    this.props.loggedIn();
                }
            }
        );
    }

    render() {
        const {navigate} = this.props.navigation;

        return (
            <Content>
                <List style={styles.list}>
                    {this.state.isLoggedIn &&
                        <ListItem>
                            <Body>
                                ...
                            </Body>
                        </ListItem>
                    }
                    <ListItem style={styles.listItem}>
                        <LoginButton
                            readPermissions={["user_friends", "email"]}
                            onLoginFinished={
                                (error, result) => {
                                    if (error) {
                                        alert("login has error: " + result.error);
                                    } else if (result.isCancelled) {
                                        alert("login is cancelled.");
                                    } else {
                                        AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().then(
                                            (data) => {                                                                                                       this.setState({isLoggedIn: true});

                                                // Dispatch loggedIn action
                                                this.props.loggedIn();
                                            }
                                        ).catch(function(e) {
                                            log(e); // "oh, no!"
                                        });
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            onLogoutFinished={() => {
                                this.setState({isLoggedIn: false});

                                // Dispatch loggedOut action
                                this.props.loggedOut();
                            }} />
                    </ListItem>
                </List>
            </Content>
        )
    }
}

Settings.propTypes = {
    isLoggedIn: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        isLoggedIn: state.isLoggedIn,
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    startup: () => dispatch(StartupActions.startup()),
    loggedIn: () => dispatch({
        type: LOGGED_IN
    }),
    loggedOut: () => dispatch({
        type: LOGGED_OUT
    })
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps, null, {pure: false})(Settings);
```

As you can see the component does have `isLoggedIn` local state and `isLoggedIn` prop, and I need to update both at the same time.

I am asking cause other than the practice, when I login the user with **Facebook** I get this error (I did not looked for where but it seems that somewhere `props` are undefined):

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'loggedIn' of undefined
```

and I do not know where and why it occurs and if it depends on this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind your method to access `this` in `_loadInitialState` method.

The simplest way would be to use an **arrow function** as

```
 _loadInitialState = async() => {
```

Also dispatch actions once the `setState` has **finished updating**, in its callback method

```
this.setState({
    isLoggedIn: true,
 }, () => this.props.loggedIn()); 

onLogoutFinished={() => {
   this.setState({isLoggedIn: false}, () => this.props.loggedOut());
}}
```

Comment: I get the same error, and I dont know how find out where the error occurs.

Comment: Is it a best practice to have same variable in state and prop?

Comment: It would be better if the variable is managed in the redux if you’re already using it, and link it directly without using state

Comment: What If I can change the value inside the component?

Comment: Change values in the store by dispatching relevant actions, no need to change values in component